# Azure Files with NPM azure-storage doesn't return access token

Tags: node.js, azure-storage, access-token, azure-storage-files, azure-sas

NPM **azure-storage** version is **2.10.3**

The following code attempts to generate a SAS token on an existing share, directory, and file. The code runs to completion but doesn't return a token.

I'm using console.log to see where it stops. The only log is the first one: about to generate token.

I'm building a class that successfully adds and deletes files - that part works. Just getting the SAS token doens't do anything - it doesn't fail - it doesn't succeed.

**Why is it not even erroring? How do I get a token?**

```
const azure = require('azure-storage');

try{
  const connectionString = "xxx";
  const share = "yyy";
  const directory = "this-is-a-test";
  const file = "short_en.mp3";

  var startDate = new Date();
  var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
  expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 100);
  startDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() - 100);

  const sharedAccessPolicy =  {
      AccessPolicy: {
        Permissions: azure.FileUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ,
        Start: startDate,
        Expiry: expiryDate
      }
  };            

  const fileService = new azure.FileService(connectionString);

  console.log("about to generate token");

  fileService.generateSharedAccessSignature(share, directory, file, sharedAccessPolicy, (error, result) => {

    console.log("getting token response");

    if(error) console.log(`result ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);

      console.log(`result ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);

  });

}catch(err){
  console.log(`result ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only have READ enabled, is this what you want?

```
let startDate = new Date();
let expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
expiryDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear() + 100);
startDate.setFullYear(startDate.getFullYear());

    let sharedAccessPolicy = {
        AccessPolicy: {
            Permissions: azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ + azure.BlobUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.WRITE,
            Start: startDate,
            Expiry: expiryDate
        },
    };
```

Are your dates in the correct format?

Also take a look at the exponential retry features in Azure

Answer (score 0):

The issue is I thought the API call was async (using an await). It is not - it returns an object directly. I also found sample code for formatting the Start and Expiry dates. Here is the correct code.

```
    const azure = require('azure-storage');

try{
  const connectionString = "xxx";
  const share = "yyy";
  const directory = "this-is-a-test";
  const file = "short_en.mp3";

  var startDate = new Date();
  var expiryDate = new Date(startDate);
  expiryDate.setMinutes(startDate.getMinutes() + 5);

  var sharedAccessPolicy = {
    AccessPolicy: {
      Permissions: azure.FileUtilities.SharedAccessPermissions.READ,
      Start: startDate,
      Expiry: expiryDate
    }
  };


  const fileService = new azure.FileService(connectionString);

  console.log("about to generate token");

  const accessToken = fileService.generateSharedAccessSignature(share, directory, file, sharedAccessPolicy);

  console.log(`result ${JSON.stringify(accessToken)}`);

}catch(err){
  console.log(`result ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
}
```

accessToken looks like, shortened value of sig for security:

```
"st=2019-07-25T18%3A39%3A41Z&se=2019-07-25T18%3A44%3A41Z&sp=r&sv=2018-03-28&sr=f&sig=C2k...NZgYA%3D"
```